# Two buttons showing two different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have a problem with my jQuery code. I would like to click on one of the previewed text that belongs to that button and the other was eventually closed.

The text should go down using `slideDown()` and disappear using `slideUp()`. How it could adjust to it did not make a mess?

HTML:

```
<div class="ata-pdf-wrapper ata-btn-video">
    <a title="Videos">
        <span>Videos</span>
        <span> </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="ata-pdf-wrapper ata-btn-pdf">
    <a title="Download PDF">
        <span>Download</span>
        <span> </span>
    </a>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="ata-media-wrapper">
    <div class="ata-downloads">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a title="DQA (free)" href="http://www.ataccama.com/en/products/dq-analyzer/download.html">DQA (free)</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Product Sheet" href="http://www.ataccama.com/dq-analyzer-product-sheet">Product Sheet</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="User Guide" href="https://ataccama.s3.amazonaws.com/documentation/9.x.x/DQA/Ataccama%20DQA%209%20User%20Guide.pdf">User Guide</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Frequently Asked Questions" href="https://ataccama.s3.amazonaws.com/documentation/9.x.x/DQA/DQA%209%20FAQ.pdf">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ata-videos">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a title="Creating a Profile" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WC_VZ5z5q3E">Creating a Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Understanding Profiling Results" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L35k080ovQ">Understanding Profiling Results</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Advanced Profiling" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQGBYkTXNPc">Advanced Profiling</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Email Analysis" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u45G0yo9sE4">Email Analysis</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-video").click(function(){
        if ($(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-video").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".ata-media-wrapper").hide();
            $(".ata-videos").fadeIn(500);
            $(".entry-content").removeClass("shadow");
            $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-video").removeClass("active");
        } else{
            $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-video").addClass("active");
            $(".ata-media-wrapper").show();
            $(".ata-videos").slideDown(500);
            $(".entry-content").addClass("shadow");
        };
    });

    $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-pdf").click(function(){
        if ($(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-pdf").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".ata-media-wrapper").hide();
            $(".ata-downloads").fadeIn(500);
            $(".entry-content").removeClass("shadow");
            $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-pdf").removeClass("active");
        } else{
            $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-pdf").addClass("active");
            $(".ata-media-wrapper").show();
            $(".ata-downloads").slideDown(500);
            $(".entry-content").addClass("shadow");
        };
    });

});
```

The code is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zp8u0rv3).

Comment: post your code in the question itself, not just on an external link. People shouldn't have to leave this site to see what your problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If y understand what you want to do with those lists, something not messy is the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-video").click(function(ev){
           var $currentTarget = $(ev.currentTarget);
  if ($currentTarget.hasClass("active")) {
            $(".ata-videos").slideUp(500);
   $(".entry-content").removeClass("shadow");
   $currentTarget.removeClass("active");
  } else{
   $currentTarget.addClass("active");
   $(".ata-videos").slideDown(500);
   $(".entry-content").addClass("shadow");
  };
 });

 $(".ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-pdf").click(function(ev){
        var $currentTarget = $(ev.currentTarget);
  if ($currentTarget.hasClass("active")) {
   $(".ata-downloads").slideUp(500);
   $(".entry-content").removeClass("shadow");
   $currentTarget.removeClass("active");
  } else{
   $currentTarget.addClass("active");
   $(".ata-downloads").slideDown(500);
   $(".entry-content").addClass("shadow");
  };
 });

});
```

```css
.ata-pdf-wrapper a {
 display: inline-block;
 background: #55d239;
 border-radius: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ata-pdf-wrapper a > span {
 float: left;
 padding: 6px 20px 5px 25px;
 color: #fff;
}

.ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-video a > span + span,
.ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-pdf a > span + span,
.ata-pdf-wrapper a > span + span {
 float: right;
 width: 11px;
 height: 18px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 18px;
 border-left: 1px solid #45bd2a;
}

.ata-pdf-wrapper a:hover,
.ata-pdf-wrapper.active a {
 border: 2px solid #309319;
}

.ata-pdf-wrapper.ata-btn-video {
 right: 200px;
}

.ata-downloads,
.ata-videos {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ata-pdf-wrapper ata-btn-video">
<a title="Videos">
<span>Videos</span>
<span> </span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="ata-videos">
<ul>
<li>
<a title="Creating a Profile" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WC_VZ5z5q3E">Creating a Profile</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Understanding Profiling Results" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L35k080ovQ">Understanding Profiling Results</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Advanced Profiling" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQGBYkTXNPc">Advanced Profiling</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Email Analysis" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u45G0yo9sE4">Email Analysis</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ata-pdf-wrapper ata-btn-pdf">
<a title="Download PDF">
<span>Download</span>
<span> </span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="ata-downloads">
<ul>
<li>
<a title="DQA (free)" href="http://www.ataccama.com/en/products/dq-analyzer/download.html">DQA (free)</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Product Sheet" href="http://www.ataccama.com/dq-analyzer-product-sheet">Product Sheet</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="User Guide" href="https://ataccama.s3.amazonaws.com/documentation/9.x.x/DQA/Ataccama%20DQA%209%20User%20Guide.pdf">User Guide</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Frequently Asked Questions" href="https://ataccama.s3.amazonaws.com/documentation/9.x.x/DQA/DQA%209%20FAQ.pdf">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>    

<br/> <br/>
```